# PHP Facebook connect steamPublish for application user

Tags: php, facebook

i have a fb application to collect FB member user ID and profile and store to local DB

and i have a backend/admin site, and i want to publish some wall post to the registered fb members from the backend/admin, thus i use fb connect, and i can success to fetch the fb member's info by FQL with php sdk.

so how to use my application account (or fb ID) to post the message to user's wall on behalf of their name (assume i have already got the right to do that) in my admin site (not the application page)?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use stream publish as a direct result of the user action. You shouldn't do it without the user knowing and allowing something to be published to his wall.

The method to do this is described in detail right here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing